# placing popViewControllerAnimated: in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear will not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a view (viewB) that is pushed in using the navigation controller from another view  (viewA) using pushViewController as usual, however for some reason, I want viewB's controller to pop the view using  `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` from inside its `viewDidLoad` method or `viewDidAppear` method, but none of them works, i.e. nothing happens (there is no crash in the app), however, i have a UIButton in viewB with IBAction that simply calls `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` if the button tapped it will work and the view is popped off to the previous view !! this IBAction works if I removed `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` from viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear methods because the popping will release the current view and all of its sub-views from memory.
the question is how can get the current view (viewB) to be popped off to the previous view (viewA) from inside viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear methods ?

thanks you so much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making method

```
- (void)popSelf {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

In `viewDidAppear` add

```
[self performSelector:@selector(popSelf) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
```

This will add selector to runloop, so it will be performed after `viewDidAppear`.